# How to write a function that DIRECTLY outputs a 2D Numpy array from two 1D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I created two numpy 1D arrays

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
```

I wrote a function

```
def myfoo(x1,x2):
    return x1**2+x1*x2+x2**2
```

To get a 2D numpy array, I use the following code :

```
y=np.empty((x1.size,x2.size))
for a in range(0,x2.size):
    y[a]=myfoo(x1,x2[a])
```

I would like to know if is it possible to write a function that outputs this 2D array **DIRECTLY**. I simply wonder if is possible to write `y=myfoo2(x1,x2)` instead of three code lines as above.

I know I can insert these lines into the function as suggested in the comment. But, I wonder if it exists in Numpy or Python "something" (function, operators, ...) like the mathematicals dyadic product of two vectors (i.e. from two 1D vectors of size m,n, this operation gives a matrix of size m x n)

Thanks for answer

Comment: Why not just define the lines in question as a function which returns the 2D array and call it from elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @esqew. It is not really a problem. It is curiosity. I know that it is possible to write `y=myfoo(x1,x2)` where x1, x2 and y are 1D arrays and `myfoo(x1,x2): .. return x2**2+3*x1` for example. So I wonder  if there is a syntax to do something similar with 2D arrays.

Comment: `myfoo(x1[:,None], x2)`.   `x1[:,None]*x2` produces a (5,5) array.  The key word is `broadcasting`.  As a `numpy` users that should become second nature!

Comment: @hpaulj. Thanks a lot for answer. At least, a good answer !!! I was reading these subjects : broadcasting, ufunc,vectorization ... and the problem of `for` loop in term of performance as I did in my question. Do you have some links to advise me ?

Comment: @esqew. If I may, look at the hpaulj answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfoo(x1[:,None], x2). x1[:,None]*x2
```

produces a (5,5) array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.  Wonderfull, There is nothing to change in fonctions. Even, I tested performance on more complex examples with `%timeit` and the performance are better. Perfect answer.